# jq to parse json and generate json output

Tags: json, jq, jsonparser

I'm working on finding a solution where I need to parse a json file (input.json) and create json file as output (output.json) after removing few lines.

Only few version will have both value (ubuntu, centos), most of the version will have either ubuntu or centos.

I tried the following command;

```
jq '.[]' input.json
```

it gives the complete list But don't know how to get values under ubuntu and centos. any guidance will be beneficial.

**input.json**

```
[
  {
    "Version": "1.0",
    "ubuntu": {
      "ver": "1.0.0",
      "filename": "1_0_0.log",
      "sourceUrl": "https://example.com/log/1_0_0.log"
    }
  },
  {
    "Version": "1.1",
    "ubuntu": {
      "ver": "1.0.1",
      "filename": "1_0_1.log",
      "sourceUrl": "https://example.com/log/1_0_1.log"
    }
  },
  {
    "Version": "1.4",
    "ubuntu": {
      "ver": "1.0.4",
      "filename": "1_0_4.log",
      "sourceUrl": "https://example.com/log/1_0_4.log"
    },
    "centos": {
      "ver": "1.0.4",
      "filename": "1_0_4.pdf",
      "sourceUrl": "https://example.com/log/1_0_4.pdf"
    }
  }
]
```

**output.json**

```
[
  {
    "Version": "1.0",
    "ubuntu": {
      "ver": "1.0.0",
      "filename": "1_0_0.log"
    }
  },
  {
    "Version": "1.1",
    "ubuntu": {
      "ver": "1.0.1",
      "filename": "1_0_1.log"
    }
  },
  {
    "Version": "1.4",
    "ubuntu": {
      "ver": "1.0.4",
      "filename": "1_0_4.log"
    },
    "centos": {
      "ver": "1.0.14",
      "filename": "1_0_4.pdf"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following JQ command to remove each `sourceUrl`;

```sh
jq 'del(.. | .sourceUrl?)' input.json
```

[`del()` docs](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example23)

---

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "Version": "1.0",
    "ubuntu": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "filename": "1_0_0.log"
    }
  },
  {
    "Version": "1.1",
    "ubuntu": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "filename": "1_0_1.log"
    }
  },
  {
    "Version": "1.4",
    "ubuntu": {
      "version": "1.0.4",
      "filename": "1_0_4.log"
    },
    "centos": {
      "version": "1.0.4",
      "filename": "1_0_4.pdf"
    }
  }
]
```

[Try it online!](https://jqplay.org/s/O94E_hLO_Q)

Comment: Thanks  @0stone0 del works with jq for removing lines. also i am trying to print filename from the generated output.

`jq '[.[].ubuntu.ver]' & jq '[.[].centos.ver]' `can be used individually to print but how do i skip one more level and use as single command some thing like `jq '[.[].*.ver]'`